# Can one define a matrix norm invariant under $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

I’m used to working with the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) of a matrix $A\in M_{2,2}(\mathbb{C})$ defined as
\begin{equation}
\left\|A \right\|_F := \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(AA^\dagger)}
\end{equation}
which is convenient to work with as it is invariant under unitary transformations.

Can one define a matrix norm similar to this which is invariant under $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ transformations instead of unitary transformations? In other words can one define a norm such that
\begin{equation}
\left\| A \right\|= \left\| A S \right\|= \left\|S A \right\|
\end{equation}
for any $S\in SL(2,\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: What exactly is an $SL(2,\mathbb C)$ transformation of an arbitrary matrix $A$? And are there any unstated assumptions about $A$ in your post, regarding, say, the size of $A$ and the entries of $A$?

Comment: @LeeMosher just added some more details to the question, thanks!

Comment: If $S \in SL(2,\mathbb C)$ then the products $AS$ and $SA$ are not defined unless $A \in M_{2,2}(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Ah sorry of course, yes in this case they are $2\times2$ complex matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Such a norm cannot exist. Otherwise, for all invertible matrices $A$ we have
$$\|A\| = |\det A|^{1/2} . \| \frac{1}{(\det A)^{1/2}} A \| = |\det A|^{1/2} \| 1\|, $$
because $\frac{1}{(\det A)^{1/2}} A \in $ SL$(2,\mathbb{C})$.

Then, for $\| \cdot \|$ to be a norm, we must have that $A \mapsto |\det A|^{1/2}$ is a norm, which is not the case.

Comment: Perfect thanks very much!

Comment: @abcdef. There is a problem with your proof: $\frac{1}{\det(A)}A$ is NOT an element of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$. Its determinant is $\frac{1}{\det(A)}$ since $\det(\frac{1}{\det(A)}A)=\frac{1}{\det(A)^2}\det(A)$.

Comment: Ofcourse, thanks. Edited my answer!